# Draw a circle with a radius and points around the edge

Tags: java, swing, drawing, geometry, paintcomponent

I'm really stuck on how to go about programming this. How to draw a circle in Java with a radius and points around the edge?

I need to draw a circle within a JFrame with a radius and points around the circumference. i can mathematically calculate how to find the coordinates of the point around the edge but i cant seem to be able to program the circle. I am currently using a Ellipse2D method but that doesn't seem to work and doesn't return a radius, as under my understanding, it doesn't draw the circle from the center rather from a starting coordinate using a height and width.

My current code is on a separate frame but I need to add it to my existing frame.

```
import java.awt.*; 
import javax.swing.*; 
import java.awt.geom.*; 

public class circle extends JFrame { 
  public circle() { 
     super("circle"); 
     setSize(410, 435); 
     setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
     Panel sp = new Panel(); 
     Container content = getContentPane(); 
     content.add(sp); 
     setContentPane(content); 
     setVisible(true); 
 } 

 public static void main (String args[]){
  circle sign = new circle(); 
 } 
} 

class Panel extends JPanel { 
 public void paintComponent(Graphics comp) { 
     super.paintComponent(comp); 
     Graphics2D comp2D = (Graphics2D) comp; 

     comp2D.setColor(Color.red); 
     Ellipse2D.Float sign1 = new Ellipse2D.Float(0F, 0F, 350F, 350F); 
     comp2D.fill(sign1); 
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Points on a [circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle) may be specified as a function of the angle θ:

> *x = a + r cos(θ)*
>   *y = b + r sin(θ)*

Here, increments of *2π/8* are shown.

Addendum: As suggested in a comment by @Christoffer Hammarström, this [revised](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2510048/revisions) example reduces the number of [*magic numbers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) in the original. The desired number of points becomes a parameter to the constructor. It also adapts the rendering to the container's size.

[image]

```
/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508704 */
public class CircleTest extends JPanel {

    private static final int SIZE = 256;
    private int a = SIZE / 2;
    private int b = a;
    private int r = 4 * SIZE / 5;
    private int n;

    /** @param n  the desired number of circles. */
    public CircleTest(int n) {
        super(true);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(SIZE, SIZE));
        this.n = n;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(
            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setColor(Color.black);
        a = getWidth() / 2;
        b = getHeight() / 2;
        int m = Math.min(a, b);
        r = 4 * m / 5;
        int r2 = Math.abs(m - r) / 2;
        g2d.drawOval(a - r, b - r, 2 * r, 2 * r);
        g2d.setColor(Color.blue);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            double t = 2 * Math.PI * i / n;
            int x = (int) Math.round(a + r * Math.cos(t));
            int y = (int) Math.round(b + r * Math.sin(t));
            g2d.fillOval(x - r2, y - r2, 2 * r2, 2 * r2);
        }
    }

    private static void create() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new CircleTest(9));
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                create();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: if you dont mind me asking. when you draw the points on the circle, why do you minus 4 from the x and y coordinates?

Comment: Good question: _x_ and _y_ are points _on_ the circle. If I want an 8x8 circle around a given point, I need to adjust the top and left coordinates of the boundary by half the width and height.

Comment: Put those magic numbers in well-named constants instead of explaining them.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
  public class CirclePanel extends JPanel
  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        f.setContentPane(new CirclePanel());
        f.setSize(700,500);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
        //Draws the line
        g.drawOval(0,0,this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());

        //draws filled circle
        g.setColor(Color.red); 
        g.fillOval(0,0,this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    }
  }
```

You can also override the paint method in the frame class, but then the you would have to calculate in the size of the window decorations and it gets dirty there...

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to take some time to review the "midpoint circle algorithm or Bresenham's circle algorithm". The accepted solution is based on very costly math operations like float multiplication and trigonometric functions.