# In Swift 4, how do you create bright/shiny/glowy views?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Im trying to create a view that glows very intensely and in the dark even, kind of like what this app here has accomplished (https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mood-colors/id545822095?mt=8). I tried adding a sprite kit particle to the view and started messing with that but it really didn't take me anywhere and I couldn't get the results I wanted. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, incase you want to know, I am working with Swift 4 on a regular single view app and I am a bit of a beginner.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you just displaying an image with bright colors? That's all that I'm seeing in the images you posted. I don't see anything special about the brightness; the iPad's screen is quite bright in the dark if you turn the brightness up in the control panel.

Comment: I haven’t tried that. I though there would be a way that it’s done programmatically some how but I’ll look into it. My goal is to create moving colors across a view with intense brightness.

Comment: Try to use shadows. I use it in my current project to achieve glowing of flashlight

Answer (score 1):

This is only images showed with bright colors. If the images have very vibrant colors this could be achieved. It also looks like there are several shapes that the user can set a color to themself. But please bear in mind that phones using OLED (as iPhone X) can burn the image in and destroy the screen if something is shown very statically.

If you like to draw shapes (like a star) there is a solution [That can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20034589/6706769)

Happy coding!

Comment: There are articles that it takes 17 hours to burn an image in on an iPhone screen. The brightness of the screen may affect life, but the colors chosen - do you have any evidence for this?

Comment: here's some useful articles about the manner: https://www.cnet.com/news/apple-iphone-x-screen-burn-in-oled-pixel-2-xl/  and http://www.businessinsider.com/apple-tips-how-to-avoid-burn-in-iphone-x-oled-screen-2017-11?op=1