# How to make GUI with circular arrangement of components?

Tags: java, user-interface, layout

I am trying to create a circular chess game. Normally, I can create a chess game by using GridLayout. Right now my tiles extend JLabel.

But, I want to add my tiles so that it arranges themselves circularly as shown in the following picture...[image]

What is the easiest way of achieving this?

Comment: i would use a jpanel where u draw your picture on and then determine where your mouse at. @jCoder

Comment: @Z3RP If so then how can I selectively put my pieces on certain areas of that JPanel, and then update it?

Comment: This becomes complex very quickly. [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617849/graphics2d-circular-table/14618776#14618776).  This creates a series of shapes, which can be used to determine where the user clicks by using it's `contains` method

Comment: @jCoder you must know which piece you want to move and update the image/graphics after you placed the piece. MadProgrammer has a great example.