# How to draw points images on edge of circle of image

Tags: android, android-canvas

[image]

I'm really stuck on how to go about programming this. How to draw a circle in `Android Canvas` with a radius and points around the edge?

What is best approach to design this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073084/draw-circle-and-points-on-circle-edge

Comment: possible duplicate of [Draw a circle with a radius and points around the edge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508704/draw-a-circle-with-a-radius-and-points-around-the-edge)

Comment: Please some one help me for same. Help will be appreciated ...

Comment: I want to use this circular image but main thing want to place multiple pins on circle edge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well; drawing a circle is a very straightforward, inside your `onDraw()` method add this line

```
canvas.drawCircle(cX, cY, radius, paint);
```

Simply provide the center point's x and y values and radius and paint object as well.

And for the pins around the corner you can go like this,
e.g you want a pin at 30 degrees; with a simple trigonometric calculation, your pin's x and y values can be these;

```
pX = mX + radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(30));
pY = mY + radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(30));
```

So you can draw your pin at these x and y values respectively, also the degree can be changed.

Answer (score 7):

the point(cX,cY) you want draw

the center point(centerX,centerY) of the circle

the radius of the circle

the angle is the point(cX,cY) on the circle.

also see the image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Dx2r.jpg

the  code:

```
cX = centerX + radius*Math.cos(angle*Math.PI/180);
cY = centerY + radius*Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180);
canvas.drawCircle(cX, cY, radius, paint);
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Comment: Your answer is suite result best