# Make a circle rotate around a point

Tags: java, 2d, physics-engine

```
Circle c1 = new Circle(20); //Initialize
c1.relocate(200, 200); //Set coordinates
```

I will say right off the bat that I do not understand trigonometry. From what I've been able to find online, I need to use cos and sin + an angle, but I do not understand how to make it happen.

**How do I make the circle rotate around a specific point?** I want to have a gap of 5-10 pixels between the rotation point and the circle's layout. So visually, the circle will be rotating around a blank space of 5-10 pixels.

Code snippets will be greatly appreciated, as well as tutorials.

Comment: There will be a gap (about 5-10 pixels) between the point of rotation and the circle's layout.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508704/draw-a-circle-with-a-radius-and-points-around-the-edge/2510048#2510048