# Change a shape of points of XYPlot series

Tags: java, jfreechart

I want to set a shape of points as a circle. This is how I do it:

```
Shape shape  = new Ellipse2D.Double(-5,-5,5,5);
renderer.setSeriesShape(0,  shape);
```

Then I get the following result:

[image]

Circles are slightly shifted. I tried to change `(-5,-5,5,5)` in order to center circles according to the line, but nothing has worked. What is the right way to center the circles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the [`Ellipse2D`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.html) boundary includes the upper-left corner's `x` and `y` coordinates, as well as `width` and `height`. You probably want something like this:

```
Shape shape  = new Ellipse2D.Double(-5, -5, 10, 10);
```

A related examples is examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2510048/230513), as noted in the [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508704/draw-a-circle-with-a-radius-and-points-around-the-edge/2510048#comment2512563_2510048) to this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508704/draw-a-circle-with-a-radius-and-points-around-the-edge/2510048#comment2511235_2510048).